# How to get bourbon-neat to work with Roots

Tags: coffeescript, bourbon, neat

So I'm experimenting with [Roots](http://roots.cx/) Static Site generator and I'm having a hell of a time getting it to import Bourbon-neat through the app.coffee file.

My `app.coffee` looks like this:

```
js_pipeline  = require 'js-pipeline'
css_pipeline = require 'css-pipeline'
browserify   = require 'roots-browserify'
sass         = require 'node-sass'

module.exports =
  ignores: ['readme.md', '**/layout.*', '**/_*', '.gitignore', 'ship.*conf']

  extensions: [
    browserify(files: 'assets/js/main.coffee', out: 'js/build.js')
    js_pipeline(files: 'assets/js/*.coffee'),
    css_pipeline(files: 'assets/css/*.scss')
  ]

  'coffee-script':
    sourcemap: true

  jade:
    pretty: true

  sass:
    // includePaths: require('bourbon-neat').includePaths
    // includePaths: [require('bourbon-neat').includePaths]
    includePaths: ['node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets/']
```

The commented `includePaths` are other things I've tried. I've read the bourbon-neat docs that mentioned needing to pass `require('bourbone-neat').includePaths` but it doesn't seem to work.

The error I get when attempting to `@import "neat"` in my .scss file is:

`Error: File to import not found or unreadable: neat`.

Note: There doesn't seem to be a tag for root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking, I was able to get this working. Here's my `app.coffee`:

```
js_pipeline  = require 'js-pipeline'
css_pipeline = require 'css-pipeline'
browserify   = require 'roots-browserify'

module.exports =
  debug:true
  ignores: ['readme.md', '**/layout.*', '**/_*', '.gitignore', 'ship.*conf']

  extensions: [
    browserify(files: 'assets/js/main.coffee', out: 'js/build.js')
    js_pipeline(files: 'assets/js/*.coffee')
    css_pipeline(files: 'assets/css/*.scss')
  ]

  'coffee-script':
    sourcemap: true

  jade:
    pretty: true

  scss:
      includePaths: require('bourbon-neat').includePaths
```